# how to filter not contain api using jquery in sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I need not contains filter for rest API using j query in SharePoint

I tried this for contains.
=filter substringof('test',filedname)
but want to know not contains ..

Comment: See this question. It may help: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101266/logical-not-of-substringof-in-2013-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 REST API can't provide a method to achieve it. We can use listdata.svc to achieve it. Using the REST API below to filter not contains a data.

```
http://sp2013/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/CustomList?$filter=substringof('test',Title) eq false
```